# Aspose.Words and Sharepoint Online

Tags: .net, sharepoint, aspose.words

We are using Aspose.words to generate documents in our project.
Our client is suggesting to use SharePoint Online from office 365 for document storage.
I am new to SharePoint Online.
So I want to know whether Aspose.Words is compatible with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid currently Aspose.Words does not support SharePoint Online 365. Unfortunately, it is also not on our road map at the moment because of our other future plans and it is a quite big task indeed.

I'm Tilal, developer evangelist at Aspose.